# Чем открыть fig файл на ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, поиск-программ

Дизайнер скинул макет сайта в fig-формате. На Windows есть Figma. Ищу аналог на Ubuntu.

Comment: вы для начала скажите, что это за файл: `$ file путь/к/файлу`

Answer (score 2):

Попробуй эти

Dotgrid, HotGloo, Alva